# Shrinkwrap/Cloth wraps around multiple objects?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, cloth-simulation, shrinkwrap

I am trying to do this kind of design (I've done this manually with a flat plane and solidify & sub-d modifiers. No matter what it just looks a little bit janky and I can't get it right.)

[image: Current]

When using the shrinkwrap modifier I get this result

[image]

So I'm not sure how to make this look better and would love if someone could point me in the right direction to help me improve this! Thanks for any help or suggestions!

Comment: how does that cloth looks in edit mode without subdivision modifier? I only guess that you would need more cuts/loops/edges before using cloth (just a guess, your blend file would be good addition to your question)

Comment: Is your shrink wrap set to vertex? if you set it to face it might fix things

Comment: @MikoCG I thought that at first and it's got a decent amount of cuts to it... Also here is the blend file, its a bit messy as I've been trying things https://www.dropbox.com/s/lizgbmjwj12tpo6/Viking%20Axe.blend?dl=0

Comment: @GrahamThomas I tried that before and it doesn't seem to fix it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Shrink Wrap* modifier does not work very well with separate mesh objects.

There are two options.

1. You can use the *Boolean* modifier to union the ax head and the handle. To make this work the handle must be wider. The axe must be solid. Your model has a gap between the head and the handle. This causes problems.
2. Alternatively, you can duplicate the axe and create a remeshed dummy axe for the *Shrink Wrap* modifier. To make this work you need to close the hole in the ax head to prevent inner faces and a mess. When the hole is closed you can remesh the object with the *Remesh* modifier. Add and apply it.

To wrap the ribbons scale them down and place them inside of the head. Then select `Project` for the *Wrap Method* of the *Shrink Wrap* modifier and give it a negative *Offset* like `-0.02`. The *Target* should be the dummy object (option 2) or the solid axe with the *Boolean* modifier (option 1).

Location for the ribbons (the *Shrink Wrap* modifier is disabled):
[image: location for the ribbons]

Result with the remeshed dummy axe (option 2):
[image: final result]

Comment: I've got this working now! Thank you very much for your help! I didn't consider them as 2 objects as I joined them and forgot but that makes sense now! Thanks!